# How to Zoom photo while capturing Photo and set Focus property accordingly using Media.Capture Api in wp8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

How to Zoom picture while capturing Photo and set Focus property accordingly using Media.Capture Api in wp8.1

Comment: Can you show what you have tried or research what you have done?

Comment: I have used scrollviewer to zoom but problem is when I zoom photo and capture it not capturing zoomed image it capture original size picture not zoomed one.

Comment: <ScrollViewer ViewChanged="ScrollViewer_ViewChanged"
    ZoomMode="Enabled" 
    MaxZoomFactor="10" 
    HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" 
    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
    VerticalScrollMode="Enabled"
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                    <CaptureElement x:Name="capturePreview" Grid.Row="2"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                Stretch="UniformToFill"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </ScrollViewer>

Answer (score 1):

It is important to realize that most cameras do not support zoom and the zoom you see in the API is accomplished with a digital, false zoom. Using a ScrollViewer will zoom the UI making it look like the picture is zoomed - but the camera is not doing anything. This may not matter to you. But it might. And, if it does, then the answer is "you cannot reliably zoom the camera".